# Decrypt string in C# that was encrypted with CakePHP

Tags: c#, cakephp, encryption

I need to decrypt a string in C# that was encrypted via CakePHP's [`Security::rijndael`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html) library.

The string is being encrypted in PHP like this:

```
base64_encode(Security::rijndael($pw, Configure::read('SecretKey'), 'encrypt'))
```

The resulting encoding is 88 characters long and stored in the db.

Here is how I'm trying to decrypt it in C#:

```
public static string Decrypt(string encode, string secretKey)
{
    var sha = SHA256Managed.Create();
    var saltBytes = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey)); 
    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(secretKey, saltBytes);
    var rm = new RijndaelManaged();
    rm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    rm.KeySize = 256;
    rm.BlockSize = 256;
    rm.Key = key.GetBytes(rm.KeySize / 8);
    rm.IV = key.GetBytes(rm.BlockSize / 8);

    var decryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(rm.Key, rm.IV);
    var cipher = Convert.FromBase64String(encode);

    string decrypted;

    using (var msDescrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
    {
        using (var csDescrypt = new CryptoStream(msDescrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (var srDescrypt = new StreamReader(csDescrypt))
            {
                decrypted = srDescrypt.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    return decrypted;
}
```

When reading the stream I get an exception of "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid". Do I need to manipulate the incoming encoded string to make this work?

Comment: I predict that the PHP uses ECB mode not CBC. The key size and block size are not clear.

Comment: You cannot derive the initialization vector from the key, the IV is prepended to the encrypted data (first 32 bytes, separated using `$$`), and needs to be extracted from there accordingly. Similarily the actual encrypted data starts after the first 34 bytes. **https://api.cakephp.org/2.10/source-class-Security.html#241-284**

Comment: Also you need to use zero padding mode, that's what `mcrypt_encrypt()` uses by default.

Comment: Funny, from where did you copy the C# example? I don't see it having any relationship with the PHP fragment *at all* other than that it uses Rijndael.